# Generating Connection string in MVC4 application

Tags: asp.net, mysql, asp.net-mvc, web-config, global-asax

I want to use the classes declared in DbContext() class.
for that I have also added one more class as SampleData() in my Model folder.
I have also added the App_Data folder inside my project.

I am getting problem while writing the code in Global.asax  in Application_start()
as,

```
protected void Application_Start()
        {
            System.Data.Entity.Database.SetInitializer(new MusicStore.Models.SampleData());
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

            WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
            AuthConfig.RegisterAuth();
        }
```

But it is giving error in first line of the code inside of the Application_start()

I have also made the connection string as,

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=aspnet-MusicStore-20130311211949;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-MusicStore-20130311211949.mdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

please suggest me how can i SOLVE MY problem of getting error on 1st line of Applicatio_Start().

Comment: So...what's the error?

Comment: @Rahul Are you adding data to database in `SampleData()` method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SetInitializer` takes a database initialization strategy as an argument. That's one of the existing strategies (`CreateDatabaseIfNotExists`, `DropCreateDatabaseAlways`, `DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges`, or `MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion`) or `null` (for no initialization strategy, i.e. don't do anything). It is not the place for seed data. That should go in your your `Seed` method in your `DbMigrationsConfiguration` (in Migrations folder).